# Finding index position in for loop

Tags: python

Is it possible to find the index of a list in a for loop without using a generator?

```
for character in string:
    if character == "a":
        print(get_index_somehow)
```

I am aware that you could use a generator in a for loop and get the index that way

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    character = string[i]
        if character == "a":
            print(i)
```

Just curious if it's possible

Comment: Beside the point, but `range` is an iterator, not a generator. `enumerate` is also an iterator. In any case I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to use an iterator/generator. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @takendarkk Bingo. Thanks very much. No matter how experienced you are there's always something to learn!